# Using italics with font-awesome

Tags: css, angularjs, font-awesome

If I remove the font-awesome tag from my text the css code font-style: italic; works ,but with this line of code {{"Andy's Bike Shop"}} for instance, italics stop working. How can I italicize text that is used in a font-awesome tag?

CSS

```
.header{
    font-style:italic;
background-color:black;
height:60px;
color:white;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:40px;
position:relative;
padding-top:10px;
padding-left:16px;
margin-left:-10px;
 margin-right:-10px;
margin-top:-10px;

}
```

html

```
<html ng-app='formApp'>
<head>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<script src="app.js"></script>
<link href="app.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
    <div class="container">
    <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-12'>




        <i class="fa fa-bicycle" aria-hidden="true">{{"Andy's Bike Shop"}}</i>



</div>
</div>
    </div>


</div>
<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o" aria-hidden="true">
{{'hello'}}</i>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Font-awesome sets the `font-style` to `normal` by default with the `fa` class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `span` tag inside like

```
<i class="fa fa-bicycle" aria-hidden="true"><span>{{"Andy's Bike Shop"}}</span></i>
```

The use the css as `.header .fa span { font-style: italic; }`

Comment: That worked thanks, but I'm curious on the point of span. With or without it, it didn't seem to make a difference